# Create directory without compile error message

Tags: excel, vba

Please help. I am pretty new. I am trying to create a folder using dates and got a compile error message "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignments". The code worked perfectly for a month but not anymore.

```
Sub Test()

MkDir "\\AD.TEST.COM\nas\Team-AB-TEST\TEST FOLDER\TEST FOLDER \" & Format(Date, "yyyy") & " Email Tracking\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & "\Attach\"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your folder actually called "TEST FOLDER " (with a space)?

Comment: Does the directory already exist / do you have sufficient privileges to create a folder there? ... There really isn't much that could wrong with that line of code, you could try build the string first maybe: `Dim path as String   path = "\\base\child\" & Format(Date, "yyyy") & " Email Tracking\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & "\sub-folder\"     MkDir path`  if the path already exists then `If Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir path
End If`

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from this line? The VBA compiler doesn't complain and when I run it, I get a "Path not found" error - exactly what I expected.

Comment: This code compiles perfectly fine. Please [edit] your question with a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is compiling perfectly.

But when you add this next to your code:

```
Function Format(s As String)
Format = "tralala"
End Function
```

Then, it does not work anymore.

Can you verify you don't have some `Format()` function defined somewhere?